# Implementing counting semaphores using OpenMP lock routines

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, producer-consumer

I'm trying to implement [counting semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) using OpenMP's locking constructs, but I'm running into a problem (the program hangs) when trying to use `omp_set_lock()` inside a critical region.

I'm testing the implementation with a simple producer-consumer program. This is what I've come up with:

```c
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 50

int semaphore_count = 0;
omp_lock_t semaphore_lock;

int A[N];

void semaphore_increment()
{
  int my_id = omp_get_thread_num();

  #pragma omp critical
  {
    printf("[%lf][%d] semaphore_count %d --> %d\n", omp_get_wtime(), my_id,
           semaphore_count, semaphore_count + 1);

    semaphore_count++;

    if(semaphore_count == 1) {
      // Semaphore was previously locked, so unlock it.
      printf("[%lf][%d] Releasing lock.\n", omp_get_wtime(), my_id);
      omp_unset_lock(&semaphore_lock);
    }
  }
}

void semaphore_decrement()
{
  int my_id = omp_get_thread_num();
  #pragma omp critical
  {
    printf("[%lf][%d] semaphore_count: %d\n", omp_get_wtime(), my_id,
           semaphore_count);

    if (semaphore_count == 0) {
      printf("[%lf][%d] Sleeping\n", omp_get_wtime(), my_id);
      omp_set_lock(&semaphore_lock);
    }
    else {
      printf("[%lf][%d] Working\n", omp_get_wtime(), my_id);
      // Creating a critical region here instead of in the beginning of
      // the function solves the problem.
      // #pragma omp critical
      // {
        semaphore_count--;
      // }
      if (semaphore_count == 0) {
        omp_set_lock(&semaphore_lock);
      }
    }
  }
}

void produce() {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    A[i] = i;
    #pragma omp flush
    semaphore_increment();
  }
}

void consume() {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    semaphore_decrement();
    sum += A[i];
  }

  printf("Sum is: %d\n", sum);
}

int main() {

  omp_init_lock(&semaphore_lock);
  omp_set_lock(&semaphore_lock);

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp single nowait
    produce();

    #pragma omp single nowait
    consume();
  }

  omp_destroy_lock(&semaphore_lock);
  return 0;
}
```

This version of the program hangs every time the consumer thread goes to sleep. If I modify it to reduce the critical region to a smaller portion of the code (as indicated by the comment in the program), then it works.

What I don't understand is: why does this happen? It seems that the producer thread, which only increments the semaphore, stops running, and then everything hangs, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Putting something into a critical section does not make it atomic with regard to something in a *different* critical section. You have race conditions. Putting a small critical section around the decrement *probably* causes the decrement to be compiled to an atomic read-modify-write, so it is accidentally atomic. This does not make your code correct, but it may have made the race-window somewhat smaller, so your testing didn't show the bug anymore.

Comment: @EOF: That makes sense. But why does the producer thread stop running if it never does anything that would put it to sleep (like trying to lock something)? It only ever increases the semaphore value and, if anything, *unlocks* it.

Comment: It's pretty simple: If you have a race condition, your program exhibits *undefined behavior*. The compiler is allowed to make your program do *anything*. It's pretty useless to try to reason about undefined behavior.

Comment: @EOF: Hum... Ok. So, if I combine the two functions, `semaphore_increment`  and `semaphore_decrement` into one function, say `semaphore_update(operation)`, I would have only one function messing with `semaphore_count`, and would get rid of the race condition. Does this seem right to you?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do if I was somehow compelled to use openmp critical sections to create a semaphore. When all you have is a hammer...

Comment: @EOF: Haha, actually, I'm not *compelled* to use critical sections, I'm just new to OpenMP, and I'm probably not used to the other available tools... I'd love to see your solution to implementing semaphores with other constructs, though :)

Comment: Eh, I'm actually not too fond of OpenMP. I find pthreads to be more flexible and understandable. Also, C(++)11 atomics are nice. It's rather difficult to implement a (non-toy) semaphore though, since you need to interact with the operating system scheduler (so the waiting thread can be suspended without spinning, and, more crucially, be woken again). Using OpenMP critical sections is cheating, because they probably use semaphores internally (or something similar, like `futex()`).

Comment: @EOF: Fair enough. Thanks a lot for your comments! I'm going to post the modified implementation as an answer so I can close this.

Comment: OpenMP has had atomics for a while now. They can be used for inc and dec, among other things.

Comment: The initial comment from @EOF is **wrong**: all `critical` regions with the same name (not named regions are all considered together) are mutually exclusive. The exact semantic is described in chapter 2.13.2 of the current OpenMP standard, but in essence, this is what it boils down to for you. So, in that regard at least, your code is correct. I don't know what is wrong yet, but this is definitely not this part.

Comment: @Gilles: That's insane, but you're quite correct. Noted.

Comment: Your program is non-conforming. Setting a lock in a given thread makes that thread the lock owner. Unsetting a lock that is owned by another thread is not allowed in OpenMP and results in undefined behaviour. That's why your code always works with Intel OpenMP runtime and always deadlocks with GCC on my system.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is **WRONG** (see the comments). I leave it here as an example of how *not* to do it.

---

As noted in the comments by [EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185968/eof), the program shown in the question is wrong, because it has a race condition regarding the update of the `semaphore_count` variable, since that can happen simultaneously in *two different critical sections*.

I ended up replacing functions `semaphore_increment` and `semaphore_decrement` by the following function, which can both increment or decrement the semaphore value depending on the value passed in as `operation`.

```c
void semaphore_update(int operation) {
  int my_id = omp_get_thread_num();
  int set_lock = 0;

  #pragma omp critical
  {
    if (operation == 0) { // Decrement operation
      if (semaphore_count == 0) {
        set_lock = 1;
      }
      else {
        semaphore_count--;
        if (semaphore_count == 0) {
          // Locking here won't actually lock the current thread, only set
          // the semaphore so that the *next* thread will be put to sleep.
          set_lock = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    else { // Increment operation
      semaphore_count++;
      if(semaphore_count == 1) {
        // Semaphore was previously locked, so unlock it.
        omp_unset_lock(&semaphore_lock);
      }
    }
  }

  // The actual call to omp_set_lock has to happen outside the critical region
  // otherwise any threads trying to unlock the semaphore won't be able to
  // get access to the critical region.
  if (set_lock) {
    omp_set_lock(&semaphore_lock);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, keeping the `omp_set_lock()` outside of the critical section causes a race-condition: Consider what happens if the decrementing thread is interrupted by the scheduler right after leaving the critical section, and the incrementing thread executes past `omp_unset_lock()` in the meantime. The decrementing thread doesn't know it was supposed to wake up, because it hasn't even waited yet. It ends up waiting forever. A lock is not the right thing for this (only the thread that holds the lock may unlock it), you need something like a condition-variable.